# HTML 5 audio tag - sourcing from PHP or Java servlet?

Tags: java, php, html, audio

I need to stream audio from a location that can't be directly accessible to a client app. To this end Im investigating using a Java servlet or PHP to create the stream on an as needed basis.

Anyone done this before?

How would this handle skip / seek commands from the <audio> tag?

Is there any way to prevent a client from caching the audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone done this before?

Yes, I'm pretty sure this has been done before. In case you're looking for code, see [HTTP_Download](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Download/).

> How would this handle skip / seek commands from the `<audio>` tag?

There is nothing to do on the server-side about that. Your browser handles that. If you want to handle that in the browser, please consult your browsers technical specification about the features of the `<audio>` HTML tag your browser supports.

> Is there any way to prevent a client from caching the audio?

Not at all. The current copy of the data is available at the client side, otherwise the browser is not able to play / skip / seek the media.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to block caching:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Someone must have done it to protect copyrighted music..

It would still work fine with skip and seek tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the audio tag from a script then you can force the sample to reload by adding a dummy GET variable to the end of the sample file name. Something like this...

```
echo "<source src=\"sample.php?rand=" . rand(1,99999) . "\" />\n";
```